# Exception with invalid dates using data annotations

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, data-annotations

Have a Json API model with a date property defined as:

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Invalid expiry date")]
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

when posting an incorrect value for the ExpiryDate, examples:

```
   "ExpiryDate":"2020-02-31T00:00:00",
   "ExpiryDate":"2020-01-99T00:00:00",
   "ExpiryDate":"abc",
```

the ModelState.Values.Errors[0].ErrorMessage is empty. Instead there is Model exception that I can not return to the API consumer, looks ugly.

```
    ModelState.Values.Errors[0].Exception = {"Could not convert string to DateTime: 2020-02-31T00:00:00. Path 'CardDetails.ExpiryDate', line 13, position 39."}
```

My question are: how can I make the data annotation generate an error instead of an exception? Why is not the current data annotation giving an error, is not the job of [DataType(DataType.Date...] to do that?

Comment: Not sure if you can do it with a data annotation, but you can do it in the controller: `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Your error message here");`

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736097/dataannotations-validation-from-a-class) will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that a DateTime value in JSON (at least according to the JSON parser) has a specific format, and not following that format is a parsing error, which is what's currently happening.

I think you'll have to take the value in as a string and do a conversion and validation on top of it. There's a couple of options. One is a custom ValidationAttribute like @erikscandola mentioned. Another is to implmenent [IValidatableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) interface on your model.

You could also convert the model property to a string and simply do a check in the controller action:

```
DateTime expiryDate;
if (!DateTime.TryParse(model.ExpiryDate, out expiryDate))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", string.Format(
        "The given ExpiryDate '{0}' was not valid", model.ExpiryDate));
}
```

The approach depends upon how much reuse you need of the validation logic.

Comment: Had to convert the property to 'string'. From Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization was getting only date "01/01/0001 00:00:00" and then no error messages from model annotations, just 2 exceptions from Newtonsoft.Json.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom data annotation:

```
public class RequiredDateTimeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Here your code to check date in value
    }
}
```

Comment: This would mean that OP has to change ExpiryDate to a String, to avoid the `Could not convert string to DateTime` Exception.

Comment: No, `ExpiryDate` remains a `DateTime`. You need only to check in `IsValid` method if value is a valid date. In this way `ModelState.Values.Errors` will contain the error.